# Flask Response vs Flask make_response

Tags: python, flask

I know that `Response` is what Flask uses by default for http responses. For specific responses format, I usually use `make_response`. Are there any specific cases where we have to use `flask.Response` instead of `flask.make_response`? in other words, does `flask.make_response` work in all situations or sometimes `flask.Response` is the only or the better alternative? Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`make_response()` gives you a *convenience interface*, one that will take arguments in more formats than the `flask.Response()` object takes.

In addition, `make_response()` uses the [`Flask.response_class`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Flask.response_class) attribute (so `app.response_class`) to build the response. The *default* value for `Flask.response_class` is `flask.Response`, but you can set this value to *a subclass* instead.

So you should really always use `make_response()`, rather than use `flask.Response()` directly, especially if you want to support swapping out what `Response` class you actually use for responses.

You *may* have to use `app.response_class` directly if it is a subclass that takes arguments that `make_response()` can't supply.

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer. I would appreciate it if you can provide some example when I have to use `app.response_class` that you mentioned in the last part of your answer.

Comment: @ettanany: well, `Response()` takes specific arguments, all of which `make_response()` can normally supply. But if you created a subclass that takes more arguments, `make_response()` won't know about those. So that's a reason then to use the class directly, the only reason that I can think of here.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!

Comment: Does calling return jsonify(something) automatically call make_response? If not, then what is purpose of make_response when jsonify also can be used to return data to caller

Comment: @variable: You are asking a lot of questions in comments. You can trivially answer your question by looking at the [documentation for `jsonify`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify) and trying to think about what kind of responses might not return JSON to know what `make_response()`  could be useful when *not* producing a JSON response.